# tabbed panel validation in Struts2

Tags: struts2-jquery

I have a tabbed panel with 4 tabs. On the 3rd tab I have 3 textfield and submit button. How to do validation for this tab .On validation error how to return to same tab(i.e. 3 rd tab). When i tried with XML validation it returned to first tab not 3rd tab when validation failed (resutl type="input").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TabbedPanel uses (or not, the choice is on you) a cookie to remember the last visited Tab.

You can't use it dynamically if i remember well:

you can ALWAYS remember last visited Tab, 
OR
you will ALWAYS start from the first Tab.

If you want to remember the current tab, insert the

```
useSelectedTabCookie="true"
```

attribute into the

```
<s:tabbedPanel>
```

tag, with the result that if you are trying to submit data on TAB 3 and validation will raise an error, you will return on the page in the Tab 3.

I suggest you to not submit multiple tabs with one button, every tab should have its own.